# Google ping failing - cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to ping Google when I update a Sitemap but always get response '0'

Here's what I'm trying:

```
$sitemapUrl = urlencode("http://testsite.com/Sitemap.xml");

// cUrl handler to ping the Sitemap submission URLs for Search Engines…

function myCurl($url) {

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $httpCode;

}

//Google
$url = "http: //www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=".$sitemapUrl;
$returnCode = myCurl($url);
echo = "<p> Google Sitemaps has been pinged (return code: $returnCode). </p>";
```

Which returns:

```
Google Sitemaps has been pinged (return code: 0).
```

Comment: Did you notice the space in the URL, after the protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these params since **`Google`** runs on **`HTTPS/SSL`** protocol.

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```